# Excel autofill formula increment from another sheet

Tags: excel-2013

I am trying to get a formula increment across my spreadsheet, but increment by rows and not columns and cannot get it to work...A1 is my formula, trying to drag across many columns.

Example, this is what I want to happen:

[A1]=Sheet2!C1  [B1]=Sheet2!C2 [C1]=Sheet2!C3

What I get is this:

[A1]=Sheet2!C1 [B1]=Sheet2!D1 [C1]=Sheet2!E1

I don't want the column to increment, just the row from the referenced sheet.  I've tried using $ (A1=Sheet2!$C1) and that didn't work for me.  I've tried populating a few of the cells manually hoping it would learn what I am trying to do....no luck

Answer (score 0):

The OFFSET function returns a reference to a range, from a given starting point with given height and width in cells.  The COLUMN function returns the column number of a reference of a cell.

You can combine these to effectively make a formula increment rows instead of columns.  In your example, copy the below formula into cell A1 and copy accross.

=OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$1,COLUMN(A1)-1,0,)

A more detailed explanation with examples is availabe at the link below.

http://www.listendata.com/2013/06/two-ways-to-increment-formula-row-when.html